# DB Testing for Web Application

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications, database-performance

I have a web application.it has 100 users and 50 of them working on a same time.every user has 1000's of record in their DB.Now I want to know how to test the Stress Test and how much time take to fetch the data from DB and what are tools available for testing DB Performance by more no of users as Open source

Comment: Google > "mysql stress test". If you read this site's guide, you'd notice it deals with programming problems. Your problem is recommend a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few toos in my mind which can be used for stress testing of your mysql server.

1. hammerdb:
   one of the open source database (i.e. mysql, oracle, sql server, etc) load testing tool.
2. mysql-stress-test-pl:
   Helps to run a test case in mysql server and also offer to compare the results of the test run.
   Following link provides all about syntax and their usages to run test cases:
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/mysql-stress-test-pl.html
3. mysqltuner:
   performance tunning scripts helps to check current status of the server provides helpful recommendation as well. Please refer following link for the script:
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl

In addition, I have not used sysbench, mysqlslap but heard good feedback about them. You can try if you have time to explore.